# Область видимости файла в параллельных ветках

Tags: clearcase, контроль-версий

Проблема в следующем: имеются 2 параллельные ветки продукта, в одной из них уже добавлен под версионный контроль нужный файл.

Как мне добавить такой же файл под версионный контроль в параллельной ветке или сделать так, чтобы уже имеющийся файл был виден в обоих ветках?

Comment: Я ничего не знаю про ClearCase, но мне кажется, что Вы пытаетесь сделать что-то не то. Файл, видный одинаково в обеих ветках — это что-то явно противоречащее концепции ветки. А почему Вы не можете просто скопировать этот файл и добавить во вторую ветку я, увы, не понял :(.

Answer (score 1):

Как верно сказал kirelagin, нужно положить копию файла на вторую ветку:

1. Открыть дерево версий
2. Выполнить checkout в нужном месте
3. Скопировать новый файл поверх старого (например, в проводнике)
4. Выполнить checkin обновленного файла